# Not able to connect to AWS corda node using Node explorer

Tags: amazon-web-services, corda

I have deployed a Corda Enterprise node using the AWS quickstart template and the node has joined the Corda test network. I checked the logs and both hot/cold instances are running fine.

Next I was trying to connect to the enterprise node (AWS EC2 hot instance) using the Node Explorer downloaded from http://downloads.corda.net/tools/explorer/ENT-3.1/corda-tools-explorer-3.1.jar.

The node explorer is not able to connect and gives an error:

```
ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ119014: Timed out after waiting 30,000 ms for response when sending packet 30] ...
```

I checked the inbound rules associated with the security group of my hot instance in AWS and that is fine. Not sure what is going wrong, can somebody please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the explorer is working in an open network and not if executed from behind a corporate firewall.